# os.walk but with pre and post actions per directory?

Tags: python, filesystems

Python's [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) function is almost what I want, but I need to do a pre- and post-traversal action for each directory.

e.g. if the tree is

```
 foo/
 foo/bar/
 foo/bar/baz/
 foo/quux/
```

then I want to do this sequence:

```
 pre-action on foo/
 pre-action on foo/bar/
 pre-action on foo/bar/baz/
 post-action on foo/bar/baz/
 post-action on foo/bar/
 pre-action on foo/quux/
 post-action on foo/quux/
 post-action on foo/
```

How can I do this? (w/o writing my own function to do so)

Comment: Why don't you want to write your own function to do so?

Comment: Why would you want to write your own function to do something if you could adapt a well-known solution? It doesn't seem to be that simple a task; I'm ending up having to do it, though, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write a simple recursive function yourself, you can use your own stack:

```
stack = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("foo"):
    while stack and not root.startswith(stack[-1]):
        print "post-action on", stack.pop()
    print "pre-action on", root
    stack.append(root)
while stack:
    print "post-action on", stack.pop()
```

Writing your own function probably gives more readable code, though:

```
def walk(dir):
    print "pre-action on", dir
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        fullname = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            walk(fullname)
    print "post-action on", dir
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.  The library doesn't give any options to do so.  However, you can limit what walk actually returns to you, via setting `topdown=True`<sup>[[link](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)]</sup>.  This can allow you to only act on some of the directories in your search.  The best examples are given in the docs.  This might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks -- it's not that I want to limit the directories I search via topdown (I know how to do that), it's that I need to do something on each directory after I scan its subdirs

Comment: "You can't" is certainly wrong.  The question is whether it is worth the hassle.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I took the question to mean he didn't want to write *any* code, regardless of whether it was in a function or not.